# How to get only numbers from string with XPath

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I have a string which contains numbers. Is it feasible only with XPath that I get only numbers from it?

For example: myString="abcd12ef34gh567", result: 1234567

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Use**:

```
translate(., translate(.,'0123456789',''), '')
```

**This is the so called "double-translate" method**, first proposed by @Michael Kay and can be used both in XPath 1.0 and in XPath 2.0.

**Of course, in XPath 2.0 using RegeX will generally be more efficient**:

```
replace('abc123def590xyz', '[^\d]', '')
```

Comment: +1, "double-translate" very skilful solution. Regex improvement: `\D`

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee that the non-digit characters will be only lower-case letters (like in your example), you could do the following in XPath 1:

```
translate($myString, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '')
```

You can add other characters to the alphabet string as necessary.

In XPath 2, you could use a regex:

```
replace($myString, '[^0-9]', '')
```

Comment: @_James_Sulak: It isn't necessary to know in advance the set of non-numeric characters -- see my answer.