# How to organize entries of XML

Tags: html, xml, sorting, xslt

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template name="displaySpecNav" match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/root">
            <div class="hidOverflow vertAlignT setCenter smallPadBottom">
                <div id="dvExpProvHolder" class="hidOverflow innerDivCenter">
                    <ul class="uSPStyle" id="uSPStyle">
                        <!-- <xsl:sort select="mOrder" /> -->
                        <li class="setRelative">
                            <a class="tfLink clickMe current" title="{grp1/tfLink01}" data-toggle=".tfLink1" href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <xsl:value-of select="grp1/tfLink01" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="tfLink clickMe" title="{grp2/tfLink02}" data-toggle=".tfLink2"  href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <xsl:value-of select="grp2/tfLink02" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="tfLink clickMe" title="{grp3/tfLink03}" data-toggle=".tfLink3" href="javascript:void(0);">
                                <xsl:value-of select="grp3/tfLink03" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <grp1>
        <tfLink01>Link #2</tfLink01>
        <mOrder>2</mOrder>
        <tfText01 />
        <cfSM1>false</cfSM1>
        <tf1SLink01 />
        <tf1SText01 />
        <tf2SLink01 />
        <tf2SText01 />
        <tf3SLink01 />
        <tf3SText01 />
    </grp1>
    <grp2>
        <tfLink02>Link #1</tfLink02>
        <mOrder>1</mOrder>
        <tfText02 />
        <cfSM2>false</cfSM2>
        <tf1SLink02 />
        <tf1SText02 />
        <tf2SLink02 />
        <tf2SText02 />
        <tf3SLink02 />
        <tf3SText02 />
    </grp2>
    <grp3>
        <tfLink03>Link #3</tfLink03>
        <mOrder>3</mOrder>
        <tfText03 />
        <cfSM3>false</cfSM3>
        <tf1SLink03 />
        <tf1SText03 />
        <tf2SLink03 />
        <tf2SText03 />
        <tf3SLink03 />
        <tf3SText03 />
    </grp3>
</root>
```

The abode XML/XSLT displays the following unordered list:

```
Link #2
Link #1
Link #3
```

How can I modify the XSLT, so the `<xsl:sort select="mOrder" />` works correctly and displays the following:

```
Link #1 (although this is the second entry)
Link #2 (although this is the first entry)
Link #3
```

Also, the `grp1`, `grp2`, and `grp3` was added in this example so I can add the `mOrder` choice multiple times, what if I dont have the group and have the following XML (my current setup and would like to keep it this way):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
        <tfLink01>Link #2</tfLink01>
        <mOrder1>2</mOrder1>
        <tfText01 />
        <cfSM1>false</cfSM1>
        <tf1SLink01 />
        <tf1SText01 />
        <tf2SLink01 />
        <tf2SText01 />
        <tf3SLink01 />
        <tf3SText01 />

        <tfLink02>Link #1</tfLink02>
        <mOrder2>1</mOrder2>
        <tfText02 />
        <cfSM2>false</cfSM2>
        <tf1SLink02 />
        <tf1SText02 />
        <tf2SLink02 />
        <tf2SText02 />
        <tf3SLink02 />
        <tf3SText02 />

        <tfLink03>Link #3</tfLink03>
        <mOrder3>3</mOrder3>
        <tfText03 />
        <cfSM3>false</cfSM3>
        <tf1SLink03 />
        <tf1SText03 />
        <tf2SLink03 />
        <tf2SText03 />
        <tf3SLink03 />
        <tf3SText03 />
    </root>
```

How would I handle either XML format.

Comment: Do you want to sort the groups by the string-value of `tfLink##`  (e.g. "Link #")?

Comment: `Link #` is just an example, it will be all text only.

Comment: I understand that, but I am asking what do you want to use as your sorting key.

Comment: Why do you want to keep your current XML format? That's a really bad way to structure XML. You're using new element names for every entry and you don't have your entries grouped into individual units.

Comment: @michael.hor257k the `mOrder#` would be great for my second XML, otherwise `mOrder` for each `grp#` in the first XML if the second XML option is not do-able.

Comment: I have a smartform in CMS where I pre-create multiple entries that user can enter information and display the menu in the front end based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better if you structure your XML like this (omitted unused fields for brevity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <grp>
    <tfLink>Link #2</tfLink>
    <mOrder>2</mOrder>
  </grp>
  <grp>
    <tfLink>Link #1</tfLink>
    <mOrder>1</mOrder>
  </grp>
  <grp>
    <tfLink>Link #3</tfLink>
    <mOrder>3</mOrder>
  </grp>
</root>
```

Your XSLT then becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <div class="hidOverflow vertAlignT setCenter smallPadBottom">
      <div id="dvExpProvHolder" class="hidOverflow innerDivCenter">
        <ul class="uSPStyle" id="uSPStyle">

          <xsl:for-each select="grp">
            <xsl:sort select="mOrder" />
            <li>
              <a class="tfLink clickMe" title="{tfLink}"  href="javascript:void(0);"
                 data-toggle='collapse' data-target="#{generate-id()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="tfLink" />
              </a>
            </li>
          </xsl:for-each>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've also modified the `data-toggle` (I assume it's Bootstrap) to name the class it should toggle (`collapse` as an example), and the `data-target` to use `generate-id()`, which you should use when generating the content to be acted upon.

The XML resulting from the above is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<div class="hidOverflow vertAlignT setCenter smallPadBottom">
  <div id="dvExpProvHolder" class="hidOverflow innerDivCenter">
    <ul class="uSPStyle" id="uSPStyle">
      <li>
        <a class="tfLink clickMe" title="Link #1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#idp31396560" href="javascript:void(0);">Link #1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="tfLink clickMe" title="Link #2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#idp31377232" href="javascript:void(0);">Link #2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="tfLink clickMe" title="Link #3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#idp31398000" href="javascript:void(0);">Link #3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need to set attributes on the first element in the xsl:for-each, you can use this in the XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each ...>
    <xsl:sort .../>
    <li>
      <xsl:if test="position()=1">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">setCurrent</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
```

and similar for the `<a>`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately due to the restriction, I can't have multiple field values of the same name. Otherwise this would've been easy.

Comment: I have to have other multiple `grp` with incremental number or multiple `mOrder` with incremental number.

Comment: Are you not in control of the XML format? Why do you *have* to have `grp1` etc or `mOrder1` etc?

Comment: Because it is a CMS smartform which doesn't allow multiple same field values unless they are inside a group, which in turns forces me to have separate group field values. So all in all, the parent element will have to be different for each entries. :/

Comment: So it's a not-so-martform that doesn't support lists.. Well, if you output just the `grp1`, `grp2` etc, and not suffix the child fields with a number, then the only change needed in the XSLT is to do `<xsl:for-each select="substr(name(.),1,3)='grp'">`.

Comment: All fixed with IF statements: http://xsltransform.net/pPzifp5/5 Thank you for the help. Your code worked for me, so far :) +1 and ACCEPTED.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, you could also perform a fixup on the CMS smarform output: transform the XML first to strip the number-sufffixes from the tags. Then you have a cleaner XML to work with. As a bonus I [updated your XSL](http://xsltransform.net/pPzifp5/6) to show you another way to do it without `<xsl:if>`.

Comment: Oh nice. Thanks. I will have atleast 10 parent LI and 6 sub LI for each parent LI... So it can get tedious. Thanks again :)

Comment: One question, I am using VS and it keep saying `matches() is an unknown XSLT function` for this line: `<xsl:for-each select="root/*[matches(name(.), 'grp')]">`. It is because VS only goes upto 1.0. How can I replace it so it works correctly? Thanks

Comment: Try `root/*[substr(name(.),1,3) = 'grp']`. If it is possible for you to add attributes to your XML output you could output `<grp1 grp="1">` etc. and match `root/*[@grp]` (i.e., match on attribute names rather than tag names).

Comment: I get the same issue with `substr`.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I am not sure why it was giving me an error before :/. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I am having to also organize the `tfText##` and `tf#SText##` based on the `mOrder` but it's not working. I will open another question that I would like your assistance please. I followed the same as this response but not working.

Comment: Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422362/how-to-display-text-based-on-order-in-xml

Answer (score 1):

Given the following input:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <tfLink01>Link #2</tfLink01>
    <mOrder>2</mOrder>
    <tfText01 />
    <cfSM1>false</cfSM1>
    <tf1SLink01 />
    <tf1SText01 />
    <tf2SLink01 />
    <tf2SText01 />
    <tf3SLink01 />
    <tf3SText01 />

    <tfLink02>Link #1</tfLink02>
    <mOrder>1</mOrder>
    <tfText02 />
    <cfSM2>false</cfSM2>
    <tf1SLink02 />
    <tf1SText02 />
    <tf2SLink02 />
    <tf2SText02 />
    <tf3SLink02 />
    <tf3SText02 />

    <tfLink03>Link #3</tfLink03>
    <mOrder>3</mOrder>
    <tfText03 />
    <cfSM3>false</cfSM3>
    <tf1SLink03 />
    <tf1SText03 />
    <tf2SLink03 />
    <tf2SText03 />
    <tf3SLink03 />
    <tf3SText03 />
</root>
```

the following stylehseet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="mOrder">
            <xsl:sort/>
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::*[1]"/>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<ul>
  <li>Link #1</li>
  <li>Link #2</li>
  <li>Link #3</li>
</ul>
```

---

**Note**:

You can capture the ordinal number in a variable, for example:

```
<xsl:variable name="ordinal" select="substring-after(name(preceding-sibling::*[1]), 'tfLink')" />
```

and use it to address additional nodes by their name, instead of by their position in the "block".

---

### Added:

For an input where the `mOrder` nodes are also numbered, i.e.:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <tfLink01>Link #2</tfLink01>
    <mOrder1>2</mOrder1>
    <tfText01 />
    <cfSM1>false</cfSM1>
    <tf1SLink01 />
    <tf1SText01 />
    <tf2SLink01 />
    <tf2SText01 />
    <tf3SLink01 />
    <tf3SText01 />

    <tfLink02>Link #1</tfLink02>
    <mOrder2>1</mOrder2>
    <tfText02 />
    <cfSM2>false</cfSM2>
    <tf1SLink02 />
    <tf1SText02 />
    <tf2SLink02 />
    <tf2SText02 />
    <tf3SLink02 />
    <tf3SText02 />

    <tfLink03>Link #3</tfLink03>
    <mOrder3>3</mOrder3>
    <tfText03 />
    <cfSM3>false</cfSM3>
    <tf1SLink03 />
    <tf1SText03 />
    <tf2SLink03 />
    <tf2SText03 />
    <tf3SLink03 />
    <tf3SText03 />
</root>
```

you can use:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(), 'tfLink')]">
            <xsl:sort select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
            <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks but just one issue, If you are using that XML, then it will be `mOrder1`, `mOrder2`, and `mOrder3` because they will be inside one XML form, I can't have multiple.

Comment: I have to have other multiple grp with incremental number or multiple mOrder with incremental number.

Comment: @SiKni8 See the addition to my answer. -- P.S. Why is `mOrder' numbered 1, 2, 3 and not 01, 02, 03 like the rest of the nodes?

Comment: @michael.hos257k I was testing it but 01, 02, 03 is fine also. I will try it out and update you. Thank you.

Comment: There are other xml tags between/after `/root` and `tfLink##` so I can use the for each twice. I am not entirely too familiar with XSL, so I can just continue with my code inside each `LI` correct?

Comment: @SiKni8 I believe so, but without seeing an example of the input and the expected output I cannot say for sure.

Comment: I will provide an example for you. please hold.

Comment: http://textuploader.com/5axzr You can see what I am trying to achieve. Pretty much if the position of the main link changes, I would want any sub link to also move with the parent LI.

Comment: For each tfLink{#}

`<ul>
 ...
 <li>tfLink # //if sublink
  <ul>
   <li>tf#SLink##</li>
   <li>tf#SLink##</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>tfLink #</li> //if no sub link
 ...
</ul>`

Comment: @SiKni8 Is the order of the nodes in a block constant and known? If yes, you can use `following-sibling::*[n]` to get the value of any node in the block from the context of the current `tfLink##` - the context being established by the `xsl:for-each` instruction.

Comment: Well the order of XML is known but based on the `mOrder#` it will change and display accordingly.

Comment: If the position isn't known, the `1` in `<xsl:sort select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>` will need to be added for 2, 3, 4...etc.?

Comment: "*the order of XML is known but based on the mOrder# it will change*" No, it will not. You only re-order the blocks for the output - the relative positions in the input are not affected by this.

Comment: http://textuploader.com/5afq5 I have it like this but nothing is showing. And you are right the output will change with XSL but the XML itself will always remain the same.

Comment: "*nothing is showing.*" That's not true. You are getting a `ul` with 3 `li`s, as expected. They are all empty, because you have `<xsl:value-of select="tfLink01" />` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="." />` and also because two of them are empty in the original. --- P.S. I suggest we wrap this up. I believe your question was answered and I cannot spend the time modifying it for every nuance.

Comment: You did help me. I will figure out the rest. Thank you

Comment: Here is the online version which doesn't seem to return correctly: http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7m3/13