# Excel - Extract all digits from a alphanumeric string

Tags: excel, xml, xpath, filter, excel-formula

***<sub>Background</sub>***

I know how to extract all numbers from an alphanumeric string using functions like `TEXTJOIN()` and `SUBSTITUTE()` etc. However, I'd be interested in a non-array entered way and thought it might be done through `FILTERXML()` as I'm trying to learn a bit more on the topic.

Excel's [`FILTERXML()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7) function is available from Excel 2013 onwards (not online or Mac) and supports `XPATH 1.0`. Therefor I tried to implement the double [translate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/translate) trick as can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7338084/9758194).

---

***<sub>Question</sub>***

So how would one go about translating all non-numeric characters a string using the double `translate()` function through `XPATH` in Excel?

```
| Sample    | Desired Output |
|-----------|----------------|
| aBc1d5_x9 | 159            |
| 12:2&0    | 1220           |
| ABC123    | 123            |
```

I tried: `=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&A2&"</s></t>","//s[translate(.,translate(.,'0123456789',''),'')]")`. However, this returns the exact same value as `A2` (nothing changed). Unsupported `XPATH` functions or faulty syntax normally would return a `#VALUE` error. So this looks like it is indeed supported yet somewhere in my syntax I went wrong, but I'm out of guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your version of excel, you can use:

```
=CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(-MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1)),MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1),""))
```

[image]

I, too, have not been able to figure out how to use `translate` with `FILTERXML`. It seems to work OK with the online xpath testers (compatible with 1.0) but doesn't seem to work with Excel.

Comment: Thanks for testing Ron. Could this be a bug? Your formula is a neat alternative though.

Comment: @JvdV I don't know. And I've not found MS documentation on using functions with `FILTERXML/xPath` arguments.  But certain xPath 1.0 functions don''t seem to work even though they work ok on this [online xPath tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html). In your case, the syntax would be `//s/translate(.,translate(.,'0123456789',''),'')`, but that doesn't work with Excel. --> `#VALUE!`

Comment: Playing around with `translate` lead me to believe we can only use `FILTERXML` to *select* nodes from XML. Transformation of data seems to not be allowed =(

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This answer is not about XPath, but provides a one-cell, non-array entered solution to the problem.

With Office 365 there no longer is a need to array-enter formulas. With the new Filter() function, everything can be done in one cell.

Using the new Let() function (currently in Insider preview), the formula can be a lot shorter than previously required.

```
=LET(MyText,MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A1))),1),
TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,FILTER(MyText,(CODE(MyText)<=57)*(CODE(MyText)>=48))))+0
```

[image]

If you don't yet have LET(), use the longer version.

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,FILTER(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A1))),1),(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A1))),1))<=57)*(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&LEN(A1))),1))>=48)))+0
```

This will also work in Excel online and mobile devices.

If you want the result to be text, remove the `+0`  at the end of the formula.